# How can I retrieve data from a website that needs a metamask connection with python?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, metamask

I am trying to build a crypto dashboard in python to get all my crypto positions accross several platforms. I can read HTML data from classic websites but how to do with all the platforms that requires a metamask connection?
Thanks

Comment: You would need to use Javascript. Python is backend-only.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use [zapper.fi](https://zapper.fi) to get your crypto positions, zapper displays NFTs, pools and many more.

```
wallet = "your wallet address"

zapper_link = f"https://zapper.fi/account/{wallet}"
```

, hope this helps. Feel free to ask more if something is not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying this now and let you know

Comment: I just spent some time on zapper but I can't see my LP tokens staked inside pools. I can see the pool itself by typing its address, but my transactions are lost in the sea of other transactions and more importantly I can't see my balance on those pools. Do you know how to do?

Comment: can you give me the contract adderes the pool?

Comment: CAKE-BUSD Pool on Pancakeswap:
0x804678fa97d91B974ec2af3c843270886528a9E6
(I stake my tokens on it via ALPACA)

Comment: i searched but i can not something easy, if the pool is 50 50 then you have the whole pool value * your portion. that is the only way i currently know, and keep in mind your leverage

Comment: @Arthur can you explain how you use the link to read in data to python? I have seen APIs where a link is used to generate a JSON object and I can read the data this way, but I'm not sure what code or packages could read the zapperfi+wallet link. Any tips on this?

Comment: @mojojojo it is called python webscraping, i use bs4(beautiful soup 4), lxml and  requests. There are other webscrapers but bs4 is pretty easy to learn. you can take a look at my profile> questions> how can my python bot...